# How properly store values in belonging rows/cells of dataframe while scraping with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

So, I am trying to scrape data from a journal.

While I can successfully scrape titles of papers, keywords, and so on, and save them in dataframe properly when it comes to collecting authors' names, **each mentioned author of the paper after the first one is stored in a new row**. The same problem applies to affiliations.

It’s making stored data useless and unrelated, obviously. Thus, instead of having the same number of rows, I get stuck with a useless dataframe.

It is my understanding that the problem arises because the program doesn’t “know” to store all the data associated with each paper in separate rows. Additionally, some papers only have one author, while others have 3-4. For example, authors need to be stored in a "NameSurname, NameSurname, NameSurname..." format within separate rows containing information about each research paper: authors, affiliations, etc.

But when it comes to specifying classes that I intend to scrape, I am uncertain how to set up the Python (BS4) code properly.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code from the simple scraper:

```
title = []
authors = []
afiliations = []

for i in urls: 
    page = requests.get(link)
    content = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    for t in soup.select(".obj_article_details .page_title"):
        title.append(t.get_text(strip=True))
    for au in soup.select(".obj_article_details .authors .name"):
        authors.append(au.get_text(strip=True))
    for af in soup.select(".obj_article_details .item.authors .affiliation"):
        affiliations.append(af.get_text(strip=True))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Also, here is a structure of section which i am intending to scrape

```
...
<article class="obj_article_details">   
 <h1 class="page_title">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 </h1>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="main_entry">
<section class="item authors">
  <ul class="authors">
    <li>
      <span class="name">Brandon Scott </span>
      <span class="affiliation"> Villanova University, Pennsylvania </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="name">Alvaro Cote </span>
      <span class="affiliation">Carleton College, Minnesota</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

...
```

What I am getting now:

```
    |Authors       |  Affiliation                       | 
    +--------------+------------------------------------+
    |Brandon Scott | Villanova University, Pennsylvania |
    +--------------+------------------------------------+
    |Alvaro Cote   | Carleton College, Minnesota        |
    +--------------+------------------------------------+
    |...           | ...                                |
```

What i want:

```
    |Authors                     |  Affiliation         | 
    +--------------+------------------------------------+
    |Brandon Scott, Alvaro Cote | Villanova University..|
    +--------------+------------------------------------+
    |...           |...                                 |
    +--------------+------------------------------------+
    |...           |...                                 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this, you should use nested loops - an outer loop for the containers ResultSet (`soup.select('article.obj_article_details')` here), and the inner loop/s for the details you want - title/author/affiliation/etc. And it's also better to build a dictionary of the details for each container and add it to a list of dictionaries than to try to bind together separate lists (you've already faced some of the issues that are caused by that approach).

---

Since you're doing the same thing for each detail (`select` followed by `get_text`), it would be more convenient to move those operations to a function like

```py
def getText_bySelector(tagSoup, selector, sep=None):
    selTags = tagSoup.select(selector) if selector else [tagSoup]
    if type(sep) == str: 
        return sep.join([s.get_text(' ').strip() for s in selTags])
    return selTags[0].get_text(' ').strip() if selTags else None
```

<sub>(This is a variation of [this function](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u), which I use in most of my bs4 projects.)</sub>

If you pass a string (like `,` /`;` /etc) as `sep`, it will join all the results with it (or return an empty string [""] if there are no results); otherwise, it will return the first result (or `None` if there are no results).

Another reason I like using functions like this is that it allows me to use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) instead the innermost `for` loop.

---

Then, you just need to define a reference dictionary with the arguments you'll need to pass to `getText_bySelector`

```py
refDict = {
    'title': ('.page_title', None), 
    'authors': ('.authors .name', ', '),
    'affiliations': ('.item.authors .affiliation', '; ')
}
```

---

Now you can built a list of dictionaries with

```py
dictList = []
for i in urls: 
    page = requests.get(link)
    content = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    dictList += [{
        k: getText_bySelector(a, vsel, vsep) 
        for k, (vsel, vsep) in refDict.items()
    } for a in soup.select('article.obj_article_details')]
```

---

The items in `dictList` will look like

```py
{
  'title': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'authors': 'Brandon Scott, Alvaro Cote',
  'affiliations': 'Villanova University, Pennsylvania; Carleton College, Minnesota' 
}
```

and you can easily use pandas to view `dictList` as a table
[image: pandas op]

---

---

**EDIT <sub>[PART 1]</sub>:** Without a function, you'd just have to do the same operations in an inner for loop:

```py
dictList = []
for i in urls: 
    page = requests.get(link)
    content = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
 
    for a in soup.select('article.obj_article_details'):
        dets = {}
        for k, (sel, sep) in refDict.items():
            selTags = a.select(sel) if sel else [a]
            if type(sep) == str: 
                dets[k] = sep.join([s.get_text(' ').strip() for s in selTags])
            else: 
                dets[k] = selTags[0].get_text(' ').strip() if selTags else None
        dictList.append(dets)
```

---

---

**EDIT <sub>[PART 2]</sub>:** If you *must* have separate lists:

```py
title = []
authors = []
afiliations = []

for i in urls: 
    page = requests.get(link)
    content = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    for a in soup.select('article.obj_article_details'):
        titleA = a.select_one('.page_title')
        if titleA: titleA = titleA.get_text(' ').strip()
        title.append(titleA)

        authorsA = a.select('.authors .name')
        # authors.append(', '.join([aa.get_text(' ').strip() for aa in authorsA]))
        listAuth = []
        for aa in authorsA: listAuth.append(aa.get_text(' ').strip())
        authors.append(', '.join(listAuth))
        # authors.append(listAuth) # if you want a list instead of a string

        affA = a.select('.item.authors .affiliation')
        # afiliations.append('; '.join([aa.get_text(' ').strip() for aa in affA]))
        listAff = []
        for aa in affA: listAff.append(aa.get_text(' ').strip())
        afiliations.append(', '.join(listAff))
        # afiliations.append(listAff) # if you want a list instead of a string
```

the DataFrame arguments would be a little different this time:
[image: op2]
<sub>[I copied the html twice to create multiple rows and added `a1`/`a2` to differentiate the copies.]</sub>

---

Even that can be shortened with an inner for loop and list-comprehension

```py
refDict = {
    'title': '.page_title', 'authors': '.authors .name',
    'affiliations': '.item.authors .affiliation'
} 
listsDict = {k: [] for k in refDict}
for i in urls: 
    page = requests.get(link)
    content = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    for a in soup.select('article.obj_article_details'):
        for k in refDict:
            kvals = [t.get_text(' ').strip() for t in (
                a.select(refDict[k]) if refDict[k] else [a]
            )]
            listsDict[k].append('; '.join(kvals))
            # listsDict[k].append(kvals[0] if len(kvals) == 1 else kvals)
```

<sub>`refDict` was simplified, so you can't have different separators for different columns.</sub>
[image: op3]

By the ways, if you want multiple authors/affiliations as lists rather than joining them as strings, you can remove the `listsDict[k].append('; '.join(kvals))` line and uncomment the next line

```py
            listsDict[k].append(kvals[0] if len(kvals) == 1 else kvals)
```

[image: op4]

<sub>Btw, with this last method, if there is more than one `.page_title` in a container, all of them will be includes, but with all my other methods, one the first title from each container would have been included. (I assumed that there would always only be one title per container.)</sub>

---

---

The important thing is **that the `title`/`authors`/`afiliations` lists are appended to the *same number of times* for a container** - that's why you need to separate the containers and append from there a fixed number of times.

Comment: thanks @Driftr95! It works like a charm! 


By the way, can you tell me if there is a simple out-of-the-box fix for my code, without additional functions? I don't know why I'm getting new rows, nor do I know how to prevent them. Although the code I previously attached isn't a completely elegant solution, I find the problem to be very intriguing.

Comment: @drupaljac [I've added edits to my answer with some more methods, none of which use functions, but all them ultimately give very similar results...] the reason you're getting new rows is because some containers contain more than one tag corresponding to the  `.authors .name` and `.item.authors .affiliation` selectors, and your code doesn't have anything in it to distinguish between separate containers